# Javascript Hangman, letters not displaying, shows numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an assignment where we are making a Hangman game using JavaScript. I have really everything working except for a crucial part. When the user clicks on the correct letter, it should replace the corresponding hyphen with the letter. Instead a number appears. If the user presses an incorrect button, they lose a point, as what should be the case. I believe something might be happening in this function.
EDIT: An example would be that the hidden word is "animal". At first it will display a dash for each letter: "------". If the user presses the 'A' button, it should then display "a---a-". User then presses 'N', it shows "an--a-", and etc.

```
function setLetter(word, letter, display)
    {
        /* Write an if conditional to check if the variable word is null OR 
           the value of guessInt equals 0 */
        if(word === null || guessInt === 0)
        {
            return;// Return program control with a return statement
        }
        else
        {
            /*  Write a repetition statement that calls the search function on variable word 
                passing variable letter as an argument and use the logical compound not operator 
                and equality (!=) to compare the result to -1 */
            while(word.search(letter) != -1)
            {
                // Create variable index and set it equal to the search function call on variable 
                //  word passing variable letter
                var index = word.search(letter);
                display = display.substr( 0, index ) + letter + display.substr( index + 1 );
                word = word.substr( 0, index ) + '-' + word.substr( index + 1 );
            }

            display = index;// Update the display
            document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML = display;// Update element id "theDashes" to the updated display variable
        }
    }
```

Here is the background code. Which I believe to all be correct other than said function above.
EDIT: I left out the other portion of the code thinking it would be easier and show just the functions in the head. I realize now that you couldn't even see the whole page and have a better idea how this should work, thus making this harder. My apologies. Here's the entire code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hangman</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- global variables -->
    var guessInt = 6;
    var guessStr = "You have " + guessInt + " tries left"; 

    // Randomly select a word from the Array
    function getWord()
    {
        var words = new Array("JAVASCRIPT", "COMPUTER", "PROGRAMMING", "OPERATOR",
                              "OPERAND", "CONDITIONAL", "REPETITION", "FUNCTION",
                              "ARRAY", "ERROR", "LOOP", "BOOLEAN", "STRING",
                              "NUMBER", "DEBUG", "SWITCH", "CASE", "HTML", "SCRIPT", 
                              "BODY", "DOCTYPE", "RETURN", "OBJECT", "DATE", "MATH",
                              "TERNARY", "WHILE", "TABLE", "INPUT", "VALUE", "CLICK",
                              "CLASS", "STYLE", "BUTTON", "DOCUMENT", "TITLE", "HEAD");

        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
        return words[index];
    }

    // word is an object and length is an attribute of object word
    // Given a string, "word", return a hidden version of it consisting of dashes for the display.      
    function getDisplay(word)
    {   
        var display = "";

        for (var i=0; i < word.length; i++)
        {
            display = display + "-";
        }

        return display;
    }

    // word is an object and search is a default function part of object word
    // Given the word "word", check if it contains the letter "letter".
    // FIND IF THE LETTER IS IN THE WORD
    function isLetterInWord(word, letter)
    {       
        /* Write an if conditional to check if the variable word is null OR 
           the value of guessInt equals 0 */
       if (word === null || guessInt === 0)
        {
            return;// Return program control with a return statement
        }
        else
        {
            /* Write an if conditional that calls the search function on variable word 
               passing variable letter as an argument and use the logical compound not 
               operator and equality (!=) to compare the result to -1, -1 indicates that 
               it doesn't exist */
            if(word.search(letter) != -1)
            {   
                setLetter(word, letter, document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML);// Call function setLetter(word, letter, document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML);
            }
            else
            {
                // letter was not in the word so decrease the number of tries left and update the display
                guessInt--;// Decrement global variable guessInt by 1
                guessStr="You have " + guessInt + " tries left";// Update global variable guessStr based in the updated value of guessInt
                document.getElementById("guesses").innerHTML = guessStr;// Update element id "guesses" to the updated guessStr
            }
            isFinished(word, document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML, guessInt);// Call function isFinished( word, document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML, guessInt );
        }
    }

    //UPDATE GAME DISPLAY IF WE'VE BEEN GIVEN A MATCHING LETTER
    // This method is called by the Hangman program when your isLetterInWord function above returns true.
    // The parameters passed in are the guessed letter, the secret word, and the current display state of the secret word.
    // This method will return a new display state of the secret word based on the matching letter.

    function setLetter(word, letter, display)
    {
        /* Write an if conditional to check if the variable word is null OR 
           the value of guessInt equals 0 */
        if(word === null || guessInt === 0)
        {
            return;// Return program control with a return statement
        }
        else
        {
            /*  Write a repetition statement that calls the search function on variable word 
                passing variable letter as an argument and use the logical compound not operator 
                and equality (!=) to compare the result to -1 */
            while(word.search(letter) != -1)
            {
                // Create variable index and set it equal to the search function call on variable 
                //  word passing variable letter
                var index = word.search(letter);
                display = display.substr( 0, index ) + letter + display.substr( index + 1 );
                word = word.substr( 0, index ) + '-' + word.substr( index + 1 );
            }

            display = index;// Update the display
            document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML = display;// Update element id "theDashes" to the updated display variable
        }
    }

    // This method is called each time you guess a letter. Its job is to determine whether you have have won the game, lost the game,
    // or if the game should continue.

    // The input parameters passed are the secret word (word), the current word display (display), and the number of chances left (left)
    // to reveal the secret word.

    function isFinished(word, display, left) 
    {
        // Write a conditional statement checking to see if the value of left is greater than 0
        if(left > 0)
        {
            // Write a conditional statement checking to see word is equal to display
            if(word == display)
            {
                document.getElementById("theStatus").innerHTML = "Congratulations! You won!";// Update element id "theStatus" and set it equal to "Congratulations! You won!"
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* Update element id "theStatus" and set it equal to "HANGMAN! Your man has been hanged! -->
               The word was and concatenate the variable word */
               document.getElementById("theStatus").innerHTML = "HANGMAN! Your man has been hanged!";
        }
    }

    // This is the main function that runs the program
    function start()
    {
        // reset guessInt
        guessInt = 6;
        // reset guessStr
        guessStr = "You have " + guessInt + " tries left";
        // create a variable called word set equal to function call getWord()
        var word = getWord();
        // create a variable called display set equal to function call getDisplay() passing variable word as an argument 
        var display = getDisplay(word);
        // update HTML object id "guesses" so it equals variable guessStr
        document.getElementById("guesses").innerHTML = guessStr;
        // update HTML object id "theWord" so it equals variable word
        document.getElementById("theWord").innerHTML = word;    
        // update HTML object id "theDashes" so it equals variable display
        document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML = display;   
        // update HTML object id "theStatus" so it is empty for a new game
        document.getElementById("theStatus").innerHTML = "";    
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<div id="header">
    <img src ="http://www.cs.ucf.edu/courses/cop2500/sum2015/hw/hangman_large.png" style="float:left"; width:"100" height="100">
        <hr/>
        <h1 align="center">Hangman</h1>
        <hr/>
    </img>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="letters" style="width:400px;float:left;">

<!-- Complete the onclick actions for the buttons in the table of the <body> to -->
<!-- include onclick="isLetterInWord( document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'A')" -->
<!-- changing the letter as appropriate for the button -->

<table>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="A" id="A" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'A')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="B" id="B" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'B')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="C" id="C" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'C')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="D" id="D" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'D')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="E" id="E" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'E')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="F" id="F" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'F')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="G" id="G" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'G')"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="H" id="H" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'H')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="I" id="I" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'I')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="J" id="J" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'J')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="K" id="K" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'K')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="L" id="L" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'L')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="M" id="M" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'M')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="N" id="N" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'N')" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="O" id="O" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'O')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="P" id="P" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'P')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="Q" id="Q" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'Q')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="R" id="R" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'R')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="S" id="S" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'S')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="T" id="T" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'T')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="U" id="U" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'U')"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="V" id="V" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'V')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="W" id="W" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'W')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="X" id="X" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'X')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="Y" id="Y" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'Y')"/></td>
            <td><input name="Char" type="button" value="Z" id="Z" class="letter" onclick="isLetterInWord(document.getElementById('theWord').innerHTML, 'Z')"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" style="width:150;height:50" value="Click to Play" id="play" class="restart" onclick="start()"/>
</div>
<h2>Let's Play!</h2>
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;float:left;">
    <h3 id="guesses"></h3>
    <h2 id="theDashes"></h2>
    <!-- Update <h2 id="theWord"> with attribute hidden="true" so the selected word is not displayed -->        
    <h2 id="theWord" hidden="true"></h2>
    <h3 id="theStatus"></h3>
    <br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is not **Complete** or **Verifiable**. Please include *all* relevant code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Does any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please select the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring out my problem. I had added something I didn't even need. The directions on this assignment were confusing sometimes, and weren't clear as to whether I actually needed to type some code on a line or if it was just describing what the next bit of code I type was going to do.

```
            display = index;// Update the display 
         //^^I didn't need anything on this line ^^.
            document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML = display;// Update element id "theDashes" to the updated display variable 
         //^^This was all I needed to do. Everything ran perfectly after that.
```

Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning index variable to display variable in your `setLetter` function, index will be an integer value, so you need to modify the code like this :

```
    function setLetter(word, letter, display)
        {
             var origWord = word; 

            // keep the word that is passed in the function safely 

/* Write an if conditional to check if the variable word is null OR 
               the value of guessInt equals 0 */
            if(word === null || guessInt === 0)
            {
                return;// Return program control with a return statement
            }
            else
            {
                /*  Write a repetition statement that calls the search function on variable word 
                    passing variable letter as an argument and use the logical compound not operator 
                    and equality (!=) to compare the result to -1 */
                while(word.search(letter) != -1)
                {
                    // Create variable index and set it equal to the search function call on variable 
                    //  word passing variable letter
                    var index = word.search(letter);
                    display = display.substr( 0, index ) + letter + display.substr( index + 1 );
                    word = word.substr( 0, index ) + '-' + word.substr( index + 1 );
                }

                display = origWord[index]; 
          // Update the display with the letter and not just the index

                document.getElementById("theDashes").innerHTML = display;// Update element id "theDashes" to the updated display variable
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this isn't quite what you asked but you might consider this useful.

Using substrings and text replacing isn't the best choice in my opinion. I would suggest viewing the answer as an object and changing the states of it's members.

Let's say you have an object Answer which has Letter objects in them:

```
function Answer(word, wrapperId){

    this.letters = [];
    this.wrapperId = wrapperId;
    this.setAnswer(word);
    display();

    this.setAnswer = setAnswer;
    function setAnswer(word){
        this.letters = [];
        for(var i=0; i<word.length; i++){
            this.letters.push(new Letter(word[i]));
        }
        display();
    }

    this.guess = guess;
    function guess(letter){
        for(var i=0; i=this.letters.length; i++){
            if(this.letters[i].value = letter){
                this.letters[i].isHidden = false;
                display();
            }
        }
    }

    function display(){

        var answer = "";
        for(var i=0; i<this.letters.length; i++){
            answer += (this.letters[i].isHidden) ? "-" : this.letters[i].value;
        }

        document.getElementById(this.wrapperId).innerHTML = answer;
    }
}

function Letter(letter){

    this.value = letter;
    this.isHidden = true;
}
```

On initialization you just call `var ans = new Answer("your word", "yourWrapperId")` and then on keypresses you call `ans.guess()` with a letter guessed as an argument..